# Can't load qhttpserver library

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I am trying to use the [`qhttpserver`](https://github.com/nikhilm/qhttpserver) library. So, I have added a string: `LIBS += -lqhttpserver` and installed this library into Ubuntu.
[image: Screenshot]
I.e. library has installed successfully and Qt can find headers automatically BUT it throws an error at the start:

> error while loading shared libraries: libqhttpserver.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong? Why can Qt not find my library if this file exists surely?

Comment: Explain what this phrase means: *BUT it throws an error at the start*, explain the steps you have followed. How are you testing the use of the library?

Comment: My app crashes on start

Comment: How are you launching the application? Have you tried using the examples provided by the library?

Comment: okay, I just saw and you're right, if I launch from Qt Creator there are no problems but if I run from the terminal if I get your same error message

Comment: No, I didn't try samples

Comment: I launch it just from Qt Creator

Comment: Try opening one of the examples with QtCreator and execute it.

Comment: I already found the solution, you have to recompile the library, for it executes the following: `qmake -r PREFIX=/usr`, `make`, `sudo make install`

Comment: @eyllanesc thank you so much for help,  I'll try tomorrow, just it's deep night here